# How i will add a time limit of pop up image

Tags: javascript, html, css

When click on the small image it will open as pop-up for 15 seconds, and then automatically opens the second one.

Is it possible to add certain time limit of pop-up image and after that the next image will open? closely same with Whatsapp or Facebook status.

Here is my HTML, CSS and JavaScript code:

```js
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        
        $(".popup img").click(function () {
            var $src = $(this).attr("src");
            $(".show").fadeIn();
            $(".img-show img").attr("src", $src);
        });
        
        $("span, .overlay").click(function () {
            $(".show").fadeOut();
        });
        
    });
```

```css
.popup{
        width: 900px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center
    }
    .popup img{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    .show{
        z-index: 999;
        display: none;
    }
    .show .overlay{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.66);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .show .img-show{
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background: #FFF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        overflow: hidden
    }
    .img-show span{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 99;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .img-show img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    /*End style*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
      <img src="http://images.entertainment.ie/images_content/rectangle/620x372/success-kid.jpg">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CX1PAZwVAAANemW.jpg">
      <img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30900000/beautiful-pic-different-beautiful-pictures-30958249-1600-1200.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="img-show">
        <span>X</span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
</div>
<!--End image popup-->
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';
   }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code but I guess you can easily find more examples for this on google.

```
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  var timeOut;
  var intervalMs = 15000;
  $(".popup img").click(function() {
     var src = $(this).attr("src");
     $(".show").fadeIn();
     $(".img-show img").attr("src", src);
     if (timeOut != null)
         clearTimeout(timeOut);
     var that = $(this);
     timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
         if (that.next() == null)
             that.siblings().first().click();
         else
             that.next().click();
     }, intervalMs);
  });

  $("span, .overlay").click(function() {
     clearTimeout(timeOut);
     $(".show").fadeOut();
  });
});
```